# QRadioButton color change on Selected and deselected Qt

Tags: qt, radio-button

i am trying to change the color of radiobutton on selected and deselected as
QtStylesheet :[Qt Stylesheet](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html)

but In this link it only refer to Loading a Image but how could I change it color and without loading Image and change border color or styling radiobutton

the requirement is attached in the Image :

[image: RadioButtonRequiredImage]

Comment: Read the documentation you linked carefully. It points that `QRadioButton` supports [box model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-customizing.html#box-model) (it has borders). It also has `background-color` property.

Comment: yes you are right background-color change the color of Box but I am not able to set button(o) color red (on select) and black(deselect)

Answer (score 13):

Read [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) carefully. It describes all you need. It even almost [described](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qradiobutton) your case, the only difference is images instead of colours.

Style sheet for your case is like this:

```
QRadioButton {
    background-color:       gray;
    color:                  white;
}

QRadioButton::indicator {
    width:                  10px;
    height:                 10px;
    border-radius:          7px;
}

QRadioButton::indicator:checked {
    background-color:       red;
    border:                 2px solid white;
}

QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked {
    background-color:       black;
    border:                 2px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting style sheet to next works for me:

```
QRadioButton:checked{
    background-color: red;
}

QRadioButton:unchecked{
   background-color: black;
}
```

Setting style sheet to QRadioButton::indicator:checked doesn't work, because this only changes the settings of the indicator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background color of your radiobutton when he's selected you should use both slots and stylesheet.

I will name your button MyButton.

In your .h you will find :

```
  private :
        QRadioButton MyButton;
    private slots:
        void changeColorMyButton();
```

and in your .cpp add in the setup of your Mainwindow :

```
QObject::connect(MyButton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(changeColorMyButton));
```

Your button is now connected to the signal *clicked* and when you will click on your button, the slot *changeColorMyButton* will be executed. You can now customize your slot.

```
   void Mainwindow::changeColorMyButton()
    {
        if(this.MyButton.isChecked())
        {
         this.MyButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: black");
        }
        else
        {   
         this.MyButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow");
        }
    }
```